# Gaphics tablet input in Racket

Tags: racket

I'm writing a toy vector graphics editor in Racket (as a way of learning both Racket and the math behind Bezier curves) and I'm wondering: is it possible to make Racket read input coming from a graphics tablet (stylus pressure, tilt) or any other pointer device recognized by xinput under Linux for that matter?

Comment: It's fairly easy to write a Racket program that pretends the digitizer is a mouse.
However, I don't know whether information on pressure and tilt is preserved. I recommend asking this question on the mailing list (in order for the authors of the mouse handling code to see your question).